# Entity Framework ToListAsync sometimes hangs, sometimes resolves

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, async-await

I've been working on converting an ASP.NET MVC dashboard page to use asynchronous entity framework methods, and have run into an issue where sometimes a call will either hang indefinitely with **no** errors or hang for a period of time > 1 minute and resolve. This behavior is sporadic and I haven't found a way to replicate it yet. Here is one of my EF calls, sanitized of course.

Note: The `sql` and `parameters` objects are defined above.  `sql` is a query in the form of a string.

```cs
using (var context = new BaseDbContext())
{
    return await context.Database.SqlQuery<MyViewModel>(sql, parameters.ToArray()).ToListAsync();
}
```

This is not the only query that will hang, however. Occasionally other queries will hang, some written in linq to sql others using actual sql queries like the one above.

**Important Notes**

- I am using async/await all the way up through to my controller, including my controller method itself.
- Sometimes everything works perfectly--all the async calls work correctly and everything loads up in a matter of seconds.
- The 'hanging' behavior is sporadic. Sometimes it doesn't happen for several hours, other times it occurs every time I launch the application.

**EDIT**
Andres suggestion from the comments has potentially pointed me in the right direction to look at the very least. I managed to catch the program when it hung up after several hours of no issues. SQL Profiler found several `RPC:Completed` events that took upwards of 15-65 seconds for very simple selects (that take fractions of a second to complete when run in SSMS). All of these were fairly close together.

I've sanitized and put the SQL being run below, with start/end times for added context.

```sql
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM Reports.dbo.Customers WHERE Date = @Par1',N'@Par1 datetime',@Par1='2020-07-20 00:00:00'
```

StartTime: 14:22:08.597

EndTime: 14:22:23.197

```sql
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM Reports.dbo.Customers WHERE Date = @Par1',N'@Par1 datetime',@Par1='2019-07-20 00:00:00'
```

StartTime: 14:22:23.267

EndTime: 14:22:37.357

```sql
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM Reports.dbo.Policies WHERE Date = @Par1 OR Date = @Par2',N'@Par1 datetime,@Par2 datetime',@Par1='2020-07-20 00:00:00',@Par2='2020-06-20 00:00:00'
```

Start Time: 14:22:38.200

End Time: 14:23:42.333

```sql
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM Reports.dbo.Policies WHERE Date = @Par1',N'@Par1 datetime',@Par1='2020-07-20 00:00:00'
```

Start Time: 14:23:46.863

End Time: 14:23:58.773

There was also a more difficult to sanitize Entity Framework query that took ~6 seconds, along with a suspicious looking `Audit Logout` event in the middle of everything. That event listed its Start Time at 14:18:25.753 and End Time at 14:23:25.770.

While I don't have a ton of knowledge in interpreting these results, it seems to me that the issue might be multiple queries hitting the same DB tables at similar times due to everything being async/await in the MVC app? Prior to converting the dashboard to async/await, I don't believe this ever actually hung up.

**Edit 2**
Based off Andres answer and what I've learned after adding additional information to my trace in SQL Profiler (see my comment beneath that answer below) it does appear that table locking is the culprit--however I'm struggling to find information on how to resolve this. I'm guessing we will likely have to roll back to using synchronous db calls for everything rather than async?

Comment: I highly recommend you to use SQL Server Profiler to trace the query. Maybe there is something blocking at Database level. Do you know how to use it?

Comment: Try `..ConfigureAwait(false)`

Comment: Will give that suggestion a try @Nick. Will take me a moment as I'm going to have to add that to the entire class, but I will update you once I've made the change.

Comment: @Andres I do not, but my manager likely does. If Nick's suggestion does not work, I will reach out to him about profiling the query.

Comment: @Nick apologies for the delay, I was pulled into a meeting. I've added .ConfigureAwait(false) to all of the calls in my repository, however this issue is continuing to occur. I had a couple successes loading the dashboard, then I had a hang on the EF call in my post that took ~3 minutes to resolve.

Comment: @CthuluHoop I would pay attention to the db before continuing looking for the solution in the application code. If the trace does not shows any issues, then check the application code. SQL Profiler allows you to see when a transaction starts, ends and any query or RPC duration.

Comment: @Andres yep, I actually went and looked up SQL Profiler--not at all difficult to use. At this point I'm just waiting for it to start hanging again.It hung once after I first added .ConfigureAwait(false) to my async methods, and since then has not. So I'll be trying every half hour or so to see if I can have it hang while monitoring it with SQL Profiler.

Comment: @CthuluHoop sure, its really easy and a powerful tool. Let me know what you find.

Comment: @Andres I finally managed to catch the program when it hung up while SQL Profiler was running. I've added my findings to the body of my question in a new edit section at the bottom. It looks like this is a sql server issue, potentially being caused by the async EF calls? I'm not 100% sure how to interpret my findings but that's what I'm leaning toward based on what I'm seeing.

Comment: What is `ConnectToInstance` and what does it do?

Comment: @ColinM I just double checked--that is logic that sets the `Database.Connection.ConnectionString` property of a custom `BaseDbContext` class that inherits from `DbContext`. No actual connection or DB processes run based off that call. I will remove it from my example code as that doesn't relate to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Im answering to add some pictures, I cant do it in the comments:

As I said, use SQL Server Profiler to trace the query. This may be related to some sort of blocking or issue at Database level.

I recommend you to add some events to have more information of what is happening:

Add these events:

Transactions:

:[image]

Locks:
[image]

With these events you can check when a Transaction begins, and when does it ends.
You should see RCP calls in the middle.
Also, with the Locks events, you should be able to see if there is any blocking transation that is locking your query.

If your RCP duration (see column) is high, then the issue is in SQL Server. Probably due to table locking.

Check these events first. Just be careful if you are running the profiler with these events in a Production Environment, it consumes system resources.

Comment: I just added these event types to the trace and reran--thankfully the program hung on the first attempt. There were no `Lock:Deadlock` events captured. Several million `Lock:Acquired` and `Lock:Released` events were captured. The `RPC:Complete` events from before that took excessive time behaved similarly--each being ~14-70 seconds long. This appears to be pointing to table locking as the culprit, then.

Comment: @CthuluHoop i didnt mean you were having deadlocks but locks. If a table is locked, your new query transaction will wait until the table´s lock is released. You should analize this with a DBA. Maybe you are having lots of insert/update/delete queries at the same time. Check also if there is not any massive update/insert/delete process running periodically. An api that inserts many entities could be the problem too. Lets say, you insert 100 objects, Entity Framework inserts them in a transaction one by one. The table is locked until the transaction is commited.

Comment: Add which events? Nothing is checked in your screenshots. It's not really clear how you're suggesting to resolve the problem.